# Ruby On Rails Query with sum and group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the following model:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :vote_for_id, :voting_category_id, ,:points_earned
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vote_for
  belongs_to :voting_category
```

I would like to know how to make a query for a PostgreSQL DB, that returns a leader-board. 
In other words the sum of points_earned for each user, sorted from first to last?

So far I have:

> `Votes.sum(:points_earned).group(:user_id, :id).order(:points_earned)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does that give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The following query works on mysql and postgress.

```
Vote.         joins(:user).
              select('users.*, sum(points_earned) as total').
              group('user_id').
              order('total DESC').
              limit(20)
```

Answer (score 6):

This should return to you a list of top-20 users having most points_earned in descending order

```
Vote.
  joins(:user).
  select('*, sum(points_earned) as total').
  group('user_id').
  order('total DESC').
  limit(20)
```