# Rails: How to sum and display total quantity by category

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to sum total quantities by category.

How can I calculate and display them?

The display image is as followings;
(item A and C are the same category)

```
order A
  shop A

    name: item A
    category: 1
    quantity: 2

    name: item B
    category: 2
    quantity: 3

    name: item C
    category: 1
    quantity: 4

    <Total>     # I'd like to know how to calculate and display
    category 1: 6
    category 2: 3
```

So it would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

**models**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shops
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
    has_one :order, autosave: false, through: :shop
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160610051929) do

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**orders_controller.rb**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @orders = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**view/orders/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render @orders %>
```

**view/orders/ _order.html.erb**

```
<%= order.name %><br>

<% order.shops.each do |shop| %>

    <%= shop.name %><br>

    <% shop.items.each do |item| %>

        name: <%= item.name %><br>
        category: <%= item.category %><br>
        quantity: <%= item.quantity %><br>
        <br>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to calculate and display in total.

Comment: You could use SQL similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957723/ruby-on-rails-query-with-sum-and-group

Comment: Did you try group and sum for that?

Comment: Generally that sums are accesible with `Item.where(category:1).sum(:quantity)`, but you should think about one query to get all sums to avoid multiple SQL calls

Comment: In the long run I suggest to cache sums in database materialized view. Recalculating sums each call with end up very long running queries.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @anonymousxxx. Although I know I should use such as `group` or `sum` and so on, I couｌdn't understand how to apply them to my code.So it would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

Comment: try `Item.group(:category).sum(:quantity)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @anonymousxxx. Where should I add this code? And could you give me how to display? Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @uzzer. Where should I add this code which you comment? And could you give me how to display? Sorry for newbie question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
Item.group(:category).sum(:quantity)
```

You will obtain a Hash build like this :

```
{ category1 => sum_quantity, ...  }
```

you just have to iterate on this Hash to display the result.

```
 <% shop.items.each do |item| %>
    name: <%= item.name %><br>
    category: <%= item.category %><br>
    quantity: <%= item.quantity %><br>
    <br>

<% end %>
<% shop.items.group(:category).sum(:quantity).each do |category, sum| %>
       Category <%=category%> : <%= sum %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @oliviergg. Where should I add this code? And could you give me how to display? Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for - thanks. @oliviergg - where and how did you learn this?